# Iterator access performance for STL map vs. vector?

Tags: c++, performance, stl, dictionary, iterator

What is the performance difference between using an iterator to loop through an STL map, versus a vector? I'd like to use the map key for insertion, deletion, and some accesses, but I also need to do regular accesses to *every* element in the map.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With both map and vector, iterating through the entire collection is O(N). however (like list vs vector) vector stores elements contiguously, so accessing the next element is much cheaper because it will use cache optimally, whereas the map won't.

But since you *need* to have lookup based on keys, there isn't really an alternative. You could use a vector of pairs sorted on the first element, but if the collection needs to be mutable this is going to be very slow. Just use a map.

Answer (score 12):

Iterating through every element of a map takes O(n) time. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(C%2B%2B_container))

Answer (score 5):

Iterating through a map may be linear but practically , it is not so efficient from the implementations in C++ . So my advice is to use a vector and use another map to locate the items in the vector in linear time .

Answer (score 3):

Use map if you need fast way of access by the key. Otherwise use vector all the time unless some performance issues will be discovered with profiler.

Comment: Access of every element in the map is somewhat more important, as it's going to be firing off frequently, but I still need reasonably quick key-based lookup (I can take out that requirement, but things will get unreasonably hairy). Map does seem to be the better fit, per Greg Rogers' answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Browsing the tree is not expensive (grosso modo like following a linked list), you won't benefit from the cache as much with a vector, but generally it's what you do when you iterate that is expensive, not the iteration itself.

Could you tell us more about what you expect to do when you iterate through the whole map?